# SQL pivot table1 into table2 without using dynamic SQL pivot or hardcode query

Tags: sql

I have seen many questions and answers given about pivoting table with SQL, with dynamic SQL pivot or hard code query with `CASE WHEN`.

However is there any way I can pivot table without using those 2?

Table 1:

```
| col1   | col2  | col3   |
|--------|-------|--------|
| ABCD   | 1     | XY123  |
| ABCD   | 2     | RT789  |
| PQST   | 3     | XY123  |
| PQST   | 4     | RT789  |
```

Pivoting to

```
| col1   | ABCD  | PQST  |
|--------|-------|-------|
| XY123  | 1     | 3     |
| RT789  | 2     | 4     |
```

My idea was to retrieve the structure of the col with:

```
WITH
  structure AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
      col3 AS col1, col1 AS colName, col2 AS values
    FROM table1 ori
  )
```

and then extracting matched values of each cell with `joins` and storing them temporarily. At last `JOIN` again populating them in the output. However I am stuck after the above step. I can't use PIVOT and have to do this dynamically (i.e. can't use the method to hardcode each value with `CASE WHEN`)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: "Don't do it *dynamically* and don't do it *statically* (hardcoded)" --- Well, there is dynamic and static, no third option, so ...

Comment: thanks for the feedback @a_horse_with_no_name! I will improve on that.

Comment: @Andreas, there might be some confusion, i actually mean it should be dynamically getting the columns but not using 'dynamic SQL pivot'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not as efficient (and not as easy to code) as a dynamic pivot. However, it is doable.

It does all need to be dynamic e.g., creating each SQL statement as a string and executing that.

The process involves

- Determine the column names (store in a temporary table)
- Creating the table with the first column only
- Populating that first column
- For each additional column name

  - Adding a column to the table (dynamically)
  - Populating that column with data

You haven't specified the database - I'll illustrate the following below using SQL Server/T-SQL.

The following are in this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b4a71e0bb50b01539ac61b798eb8fc0f) so you can see what's going on.

```
CREATE TABLE #ColNames (ColNum int IDENTITY(1,1), ColName nvarchar(100), ColNametxt nvarchar(100));

INSERT INTO #ColNames (ColName, ColNametxt)
    SELECT DISTINCT QUOTENAME(Col1), Col1
    FROM table1;
```

This will populate the #ColNames table with the values `1, [ABCD], ABCD`, `2, [PQST], PQST`.

The next step is to create your output table - I'll call it #pvttable

```
CREATE TABLE #pvttable (col1 nvarchar(100) PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO #pvttable (col1)
    SELECT DISTINCT Col3
    FROM table1;
```

This creates your table with 1 column (col1) with values `XY123` and `RT789`).

The write your favorite loop (e.g., cursor, while loop). In each step

- Get the next column name
- Add the column to the table
- Update that column with appropriate data

e.g., the following is an illustrative example with your data.

```
DECLARE @CustomSQL nvarchar(4000);
DECLARE @n int = 1;
DECLARE @ColName nvarchar(100);
DECLARE @ColNametxt nvarchar(100);

SELECT      @ColName = ColName,
            @ColNameTxt = ColNameTxt
    FROM    #ColNames 
    WHERE   ColNum = @n;

WHILE @ColName IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN

    SET @CustomSQL = N'ALTER TABLE #pvttable ADD ' + @ColName + N' nvarchar(100);';
    EXEC (@CustomSQL);

    SET @CustomSQL = 
        N'UPDATE #pvttable SET ' + @Colname + N' = table1.col2'
        + N' FROM #pvttable INNER JOIN table1 ON #pvttable.col1 = table1.col3'
        + N' WHERE table1.col1 = N''' + @ColNametxt + N''';';
    EXEC (@CustomSQL);

    SET @n += 1;

    SET @ColName = NULL;
    SET @ColNametxt = NULL;

    SELECT      @ColName = ColName,
                @ColNameTxt = ColNameTxt
        FROM    #ColNames 
        WHERE   ColNum = @n;

    END;

SELECT * FROM #pvttable;
```

Comment: thanks @seanb! I couldn't use SQL Server/T-SQL hence can't add and update to the table by using the loop unfortunately. But your methodology works! I'm having very limited functions that I can use, but your steps inspired me to continue playing around with what I can do further with the methodology